# Show n that $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(\mathbb{R}, \rho_2 )$.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with 2–norm metric $\rho_2(x,y) = ||y −x||_2$ . Show that $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(\mathbb{R}, \rho_2 )$.

How do I show this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality this might help

Comment: @IAmNoOne how would you go about using the Minkowski inequality to show $\{x_k\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: This is not specific to your metric. **A convergent sequence in any metric space is  Cauchy** and any book that deals with metric spaces has this statement.

Comment: @Okbko see the other answers. If you dont know this inequality you might have to prove it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the limit of $(x_k)$ by $L$.

For $n,m \in \mathbb N$ we have

$$||x_n-x_m||_2 =||x_n-L-(x_m-L)||_2 \le ||x_n-L||_2+||x_m-L||_2.$$

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Well the $2$-norm is a metric, so it satisfies the triangle inequality.  Let $L$ be the limit.  Then given $\epsilon\gt0$, choose $N$ such that $||x_n-L||_2\lt\epsilon/2$ for all $n\ge N$.  Then $||x_n-x_m||_2=||x_n-L+L-x_m||_2\le||x_n-L||_2+||x_m-L||_2=\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$ for all $n,m\ge N$.

Thus $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy.